# Table Per Inheritance and Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Table per Hierarchy (TPH).
For example we have a base class for all entities:

```
public abstract class Entity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual bool IsTransient()
        {
            return Id == default(int);
        }
    }
```

And base class for several entitites:

```
public abstract class Event:Entity
    {
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

        public int  Duration { get; set; }
    }

public class Film:Event
    {
        public string Director { get; set; }

        public string ActorList { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

public class Concert:Event
    {
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```

My context:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
    {
        public MyContext():base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

        public virtual void Commit()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

This is base repository:

```
public class GenericRepository : IRepository
{
  //...   

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
            {
                return GetQuery<TEntity>().AsEnumerable();
            } 

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
            {          
                var entityName = GetEntityName<TEntity>();
                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<TEntity>(entityName);
            }

private string GetEntityName<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            string entitySetName = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext
                 .MetadataWorkspace
                 .GetEntityContainer(((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace)  
                 .BaseEntitySets.First(bes => bes.ElementType.Name == typeof(TEntity).Name).Name;

            return string.Format("{0}.{1}", ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.DefaultContainerName, entitySetName);
        }

    }
```

Next, create context and repository:

```
var context = new MyContext();
EventRepository repository = new EventRepository(context);
var films = repository.GetAll<Film>();
```

But I get exception (in the `GetEntityName` method): the sequence does not have elements.
I think it because there are no `Film` table in the DB. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the need of `GetEntityName` in the repository you are showing. For `GetQuery` you can use the `DbContext` API directly and don't need to access the underlying `ObjectContext` or `MetadataWorkspace`:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{          
    return DbContext.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

This returns a `DbSet<TEntity>` (which is an `IQueryable<TEntity>`). I am not 100% sure if that also works if `TEntity` is derived but the [MSDN documentation about `DbSet<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) says: "*The type can be derived type as well as base type.*" So, I would hope that the `Set<TEntity>()` method is allowed for derived types as well.